# What would cause Xcode MacOs app to point main bundle at "/Applications/Xcode.app"?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm struggling to write my first Swift3 app - a screensaver because I can't reference any local files. After hours of debugging and setting up a Playground I found that the Bundle.main.bundlePath is not pointing at my app but rather "/Applications/Xcode.app". Which explains why in the code below - video.mp4 is never found but I get nil back from selecting the Bundle by identifier as well.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? My one local file (video.mp4) is readable, copied as a Bundle Resource and has no spurious xattrs. I'm stuck! Any help appreciated.

Running 10.12.3/Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3.0.2

Playground code below:

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

import AVKit
import AVFoundation
var frameRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600)
var mainView = NSView(frame: frameRect)


let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.modprods.koorigras-test.Playground")
debugPrint(bundle)

debugPrint(Bundle.main.bundlePath)
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video",ofType:"mp4") else {
    debugPrint("not found")
    exit(1)
}
```

Comment: `Bundle.main.bundlePath is not pointing at my app but rather "/Applications/Xcode.app"` This is because you're doing this in a Playground. A Playground has no own bundle, it's part of Xcode. Run this line in your real app and it will give you the actual bundle path as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As per Eric's comment, this is correct behavior for a Playground.

For other n00bs, creating a new Playground inside your workspace results in greyed out Sources and Resources folders that if you try to show in finder nothing happens (because they don't exist). To access local files from within a new Playground

- create the Resources subfolder
- copy the asset to Resource
- make sure Copy Bundle Resources includes this asset for the target

It appears there is no way of accessing other bundles from within a Playground.